# Visual Studio 2019 (C#): The type or namespace name EnvDTE could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to use the `EnvDTE` interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) in order to able auto-generation of projects. However, when I have the following line of code:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = LaunchVsDte(isPreRelease: false);
```

I get an error, stating:

> The type or namespace 'EnvDTE' could not be found

And in the suggestions, it does not show any import statements I can use.

Comment: Have you already enabled the [Visual studio SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2019) on your installation?

Comment: @MXD Yes, I have enabled Visual Studio SDK on my installation.

Comment: Hi,@Adam Lee.You can import the assembly by adding a reference.

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click the reference in the explorer -> add reference -> select EnvDTE in the .net framework tab(Tick the checkbox) -> OK -> then use EnvDTE in the code;

Comment: Does it help you？